# Project not deploying due to "Project facet Java 1.7 is not supported by this server."

Tags: java, eclipse, weblogic, facet

I am having trouble trying to deploy a WAR project on Oracle Weblogic Server 11gR1 (10.3.5), tried both to deploy it in an EAR project, or by itself as a war.

The error I get is this:

"Project facet Java 1.7 is not supported by this server."

The problem is that there is no Project Facet Java 1.7 in this project. The facets selected are this:

- Dynamic Web Module 2.5
- Java 1.6
- JavaScript 1.0

I only have JRE6 installed in eclipse and I'm using it as default.

Other projects are deploying succesfully.

I found a workaround, deploying the EAR empty, and then adding the WAR project to the EAR. But in that case I get other problems at runtime which shouldn't be happening, I guess caused by the tricky solution.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weblogic 10.3.5 only supports JDK6. If you want to use JDK 7, you'll need version 10.3.6 as outlined [here (10.3.5)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18840/install_config_win.htm#EOHWL114) and [here (10.3.6)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24902_01/doc.91/e18840/install_config_10_3_6.htm#EOHWL187).

Cheers,

Comment: I know, but int this case I don´t want to use JDK7, the problem is that despite using JDK 6, somehow the server identifies the project as if it is using java facet 1.7.

Answer (score 2):

I just solved the issue, I had java project facet 1.7 in a project included in the war.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you !  I already lost an afternoon on that problem in myeclipse.  The problem was that my project depends on another project which had facet Java 1.7.